# Rounded of a float with a decimal

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point, decimal

Do someone know if there is a method in order to round a float two numbers after the comme.

Examples :

```
10.28000 -> 10.3
13.97000 -> 14.0
5.41000 -> 5.4
```

Thanks a lot !

Regards,
Sébastien ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSNumberFormatter to create a string with the specified faction digits.

```
float num = 10.28000;

formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num];
NSString *newNumString = [formatter stringFromNumber:value];
```

Comment: ... and what will the NSNumberFormatter output instead of a string?

Comment: It will give you an nsnumber.  You can then get the string or float value.

Comment: And then you'll want a string at some point to display it somewhere.

Comment: Pardon me, but you're instanciating a NSNumberFormatter here, and never use it to format `num`.

Comment: Cyrille - editted, looked at the wrong piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
float aFloatValue = 3.1415926;
NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01.1f", aFloatValue];
NSLog(@"Formatted: %@", formatted);
```

Think of it as a good old `sprintf`.

Comment: Question was about rounding of float, not about formatting it into the string.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try

```
float num = 10.28000
float result = (roundf(num * 10.0))/10.0;
```

(multiply by 10, then round, then divide by 10 again)
don't forget the .0 so that the division is by a float and not by an integer, which will round it again

Answer (score 1):

The pure Cocoa way with NSRoundPlain behaviour:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberForFloat:(float)f_
```

{

```
NSNumber *number                           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f_];
NSDecimal decimal                          = [number decimalValue];
NSDecimalNumber *originalDecimalNumber     = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:decimal];
NSDecimalNumberHandler *roundingBehavior   = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                              scale:0
                                              raiseOnExactness:NO
                                              raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                              raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                              raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

return [originalDecimalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:roundingBehavior];
```

}

since NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber, to obtain the primitive float call -[NSDecimalNumber floatValue]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
float myFloat = 10.4246f;
myFloat = ((int) ((myFloat * 100) + 5)) / 100.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float fval = 1.54f;
float nfval = ceilf(fval * 10.0f + 0.5f)/10.0f;
```